# Perl module to substitute the wget command

Tags: perl

I am using currently `wget` to send information to a database. Is there a Perl module that can provide the same functionality of the wget command?

Update: Preferable a module which doesn't need installation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Your question is off-topic for SO because it asks for a tool recommendation. It also does not contain enough information. Please [edit] the question and tell us what database, and how you connect to it. _wget_ is essentially an HTTP client (like _curl_). So I presume you are talking to some kind of NOSQL database that has an HTTP API. Maybe Couchbase or MongoDB or something like that. There are modules for those on CPAN. If you want to implement simple HTTP requests in Perl, those are documented well. A simple search will give a lot of resources.

Comment: Also, please take a moment to read the [faq] and take the Stack Overflow [tour] to learn more about what's on-topic here, and how to ask good questions. Thank you. :)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you want to achieve "wget functionality" on one hand, yet "a module without installation" on the other - seems a bit unrealistic - most specific behaviour outside of core perl *comes from* installed CPAN modules.

Comment: @DravSloan pure perl modules can just be copied with a minor change to your code, without cpan or ppm installation. They're just scripts after all

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche but that still requires some form of "installation", it doesn't get to your filesystem by magic :)

Comment: @DravSloan now you're simply splitting hairs. Your argument is terrible, if you copy and paste the string "abc" to a text file on a computer your argument is that you've installed it?

Comment: You're asking for an HTTP client. The "standard" Perl HTTP client is the [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) suite of modules. But that requires installation. If you're using a modern version of Perl (5.14+) then that will include [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) which is a small HTTP client.

Comment: @DaveCross thank you kindly. Yes, this is what I was searching for.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche No my point is that you still have to goto CPAN or similar, locate the module, get the source code, open a file with the correct/name and path and "paste" the code. That is _still_ better serviced via CPAN (even for pure perl), because at least then unit tests and dependancies can also be checked. I'd like to see a "replacement for wget" than wouldn't need a number of modules, and some form of "installation".

Comment: @DravSloan also HTTP::Tiny is pure perl and depends on core modules which can replicate wget functionality easily

Comment: @DravSloan when I meant "wget functionalitty without module installation" I was wondering if there is a module which comes with the Perl distribution that I could have missed

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche: Your sarcasm isn't welcome. It is inadvisable to simply copy the source of modules into place. Every module comes with a specific installation procedure which may include non-obvious steps, and a test suite that will ensure that the module is working correctly. cpan also maintains a database of installed modules on your system which is clearly not updated by such a manual procedure. Those who feel unable to install modules properly usually have a misconception about what options are available, and it is better to encourage them than to advocate manhandling things into place.

Comment: @DaveCross: Thank you. I was unaware that `HTTP::Tiny` was in core.

Comment: @Borodin where did I say "the source of modules into place". "Every module comes with a specific installation procedure which may include non-obvious steps" all steps are documented in the module source, otherwise cpan wouldn't be able to install it. All of which can be done manually if need be. "cpan also maintains a database of installed modules on your system which is clearly not updated by such a manual procedure." The entire point of my answer is that you can use the modules code without installing the module.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche: You said *"pure perl modules can just be copied"*. Objecting to my *"into place"* seems strange and leaves me wondering what you actually intended. The steps to build the module are included as `Makefile.PL` which generates a file for `make` to interpret to build and install the module. It is far from being straightforward to interpret, and the vast majority of systems are equipped with the necessary command-line tools to install the module properly, even on Windows. There is no need to encourage anyone to "just copy" it.

Comment: this was in response to the technically incorrect statement made earlier `"a module without installation" on the other - seems a bit unrealistic`. I didn't encourage anyone to do this, simply stated that it is not impossible and can be done. Try reading the context before getting on your high horse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) is in bundled with perl since perl 5.14. This should be enough to send a GET or POST request to an HTTP server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though the credit belgongs to @Dave Cross